# swift use class instances to implement variable

Tags: class, swift2, viewcontroller

My aim is to implement first a viewtable with json data in a view controller.
Then in another viewcontroller i want to choose some record from table to view.

First my class Route is above

```
class Route {

var id: Int?
var travelTimeSeconds: Int?
var condition:String?
var lastUpdate:String?
var title:String?

var backup = [Route]()


init(json: NSDictionary) {
    self.id = json["id"] as? Int
    self.travelTimeSeconds = json["travelTimeSeconds"] as? Int
    self.condition = json["condition"] as? String
    self.lastUpdate = json["lastUpdate"] as? String
    self.title = json["title"] as? String
}

init(){}

func findRoutes(predferedroute:String)->[Route] {

    let jsonurl = NSURL(string: predferedroute)!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(jsonurl) { (data,response, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            if let urlcontent = data {

                do{

                    let jsonresult =   try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlcontent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)



                    if let routeArray = jsonresult["result"] as? [NSDictionary] {

                        for item in routeArray {
                            self.backup.append(Route(json: item))
                        }//end for

                    }//end if


                }//end do
                catch {

                    print("Serialization error")

                }//end catch

            }//end if

        })//end dispatch
    }//end task
    task.resume()
    return self.backup
}//end findRoutes
```

}
in the first view cotroller i write the following code

```
class MenuPageViewController: UIViewController{


var routes = [Route]()

var implementroutes = Route()

var allroutes:String = "http://quickweb.gr/itsweb/webservices/json?op=GetAll"

var activeRoutes:String = "http://quickweb.gr/itsweb/webservices/json?op=GetActive"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("palios55", forKey: "StartUp")

    let nickname1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("StartUp")!


    print(nickname1)

  routes = implementroutes.findRoutes(allroutes)

    routes = implementroutes.backup



}//end viewload



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

the other delegates for table view works
but still remain nil the routes for both of two codes:

routes = implementroutes.findRoutes(allroutes)
routes = implementroutes.backup

Does i miss something with viewcontrollers and classes?
if i use the same code directly in tableview it works.

Comment: You missed something with "async".  Your `findRoutes` method will return before `task` executes.  Add some log messages to see the order of how things happen.

Comment: yes this happens. but when i use the method out from viewDidLoad it works fine. i dont know if something goes wrong with the instances